# 400 Bad Request in Google Oauth2 for access token

Tags: python, django, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am setting up Google Oauth 2 in my django app. I am able to get the code but when I try and exchange it for an access token I get a `Bad Request` error. This is my code:

```
code = request.GET['code']
state = request.GET['state']
access_token_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token"
payload = {
    'grant_type' : "authorization_code",
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
    'code': code,
    'redirect_uri': "http://127.0.0.1:8888/home",
}
payload = urllib.urlencode(payload)
r = urllib2.Request(access_token_url, payload, headers={"Content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
response = urllib2.urlopen(r)
```

What could be wrong?

When I try the same using POSTMAN (google chrome app), I get

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"
}
```

I know there are similar questions here on so but I am still not able to figure out the error.

Comment: Hi Archit I am working on same thing but using php and i was wondering what is this variable "code" and where do you get it from?

Comment: `code` is passed as an argument when user authorizes you google app. You can use it to exchange it for an `access token` of the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a stupid mistake. I had given the wrong `redirect_uri`. Anyway, the error message from google API wasn't much helpful.

Comment: I am passing the correct redirect URI but still getting the redirect_uri mismatch error.

Answer (score 0):

add to payload

```
grant_type=authorization_code
```